# How to do tmux live streaming to a webapp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, video-streaming, tmux

Is there a way to live stream a tmux session to web application?

Is there a proper preferred way of doing something like this to be shared with other developers online who don't have access to a console.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a little overkill, but seems like it would solve your problem:
http://liftoffsoftware.com/Products/GateOne